# How to keep Autoresizingmask layout same in portrait and also in landscape in iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, xcode, autoresizingmask

I made my full application in Autoresizingmask in portrait.
Now, I also want the same layout for landscape but when I go to portrait to landscape it shows bad layout.
How can I get the same layout as the portrait in landscape without using autolayout.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: To support both use autolayout or recalculate all the frames manually and set the frames for the different orientation.

Comment: I honestly do not think that it is possible to copy the layout for both orientations without using AutoLayout.  You could recalculate all the frames manually as @agibson007 stated, but at that point, why not use AutoLayout?  Setting traits using autolayout is the easiest why to handle orientation layout changes.

Comment: My guess is auto layout seems too difficult but it really is not.  Try using equal heights and equal widths constraints(They work like AutoResizing) and set the multiplier to the percentage you want the view to take of the width and height.  Even better do that and place the views in UIStackView and vary for traits for cool layouts between portrait and landscape.

Comment: thank you @ agibson and @ Jacob Boyd. But I don't have time to give auto layout. If I change then it changes the look in all app. You both correct but in some view, I won't be able to give auto layout. Because the project is big and I used many accordions in my project and it's should take more time to set in the auto layout. if any short-way to complete in short time. thank you once again :).